# Cross-platform Mobile Development Language

Tags: android, mobile

I am new to mobile development with a requirement to develop applications for Android and IOS. My programming background is in C#.

Which is the best language and framework to start developing mobile applications?
Is it better to use native development or use cross-platform frameworks?

Please suggest frameworks and languages with respect to ease of development, development support etc..

Answer (score 2):

I am no expert in Cross Platform Mobile Development (in fact, I was just searching for a cross platform mobile development languages/frameworks), but you could take a look at [Xamarin](https://www.xamarin.com/), especially as you have a C# Background.

You may also want to take a look at [Apache Cordova](https://cordova.apache.org/) (and [Adobe Phonegap](http://phonegap.com/)), they use HTML+CSS+JavaScript.

I recently found [Flutter](https://flutter.io/), the development language is [Dart](https://www.dartlang.org/) and it's an early stage OSS project (as of 2016 october) and [Haxe](https://haxe.org). They both seem like active projects, so worth following the progress on GitHub.

If I had to choose and I already had skills in C#, I'd go with Xamarin.

Answer (score 2):

I strongly recommend you give a try to Flutter... It just came out from Google... It's in Beta, but Google heavily used it until now in production mobile applications. It uses Dart, as a programming language and it's awesome. If you have a background in C# (or similar languages, like Java for example) you won't have any problems - it's quick to learn and there are a bunch of tutorials already.

Do a search on YouTube for Flutter, and also on medium...

Here's the website link: http://flutter.io

You can also download some sample applications with all the Android / iOs widgets you can use in a Flutter application. Here's the app for Android: https://play.google.com/store/apps/details?id=io.flutter.gallery&hl=en

The key difference between Flutter and React native for example is that there's no Javascript bridge... and it compiles to native code. You also write the code once, and it will work by default both on Android and iOs... Hack, you can even switch to iOs widgets on an Android phone.

It's AWESOME!!!