Is it possible to build Android Apps with Swift
As an iOS developer, I'm learning Dart language recently. After a couple of days self-learning, I admit Dart is a powerful and modern language. But to be honest, I dislike the syntactic sugar, it looks like wired for me. So can someone tell me is there any way to build cross-platform apps using Swift?
build cross-platform apps using Swift

Check this;
https://stackoverflow.com/questions/62025245/compiling-swift-for-android

Not currently. But there is some cool stuff going on in the community, like this: https://skip.tools/

In Android you can use NDK for business logic. You can write NDK libs with Swift and use them in Android app.

thanks to @Sameri11 he introduced a tool called Skip. https://skip.tools

https://readdle.com/blog/swift-for-android-our-experience-and-tools

There is a way, I guess, but in my opinion it's kinda immature at the point. Im talking about Skip. In its core, it's just a transpiler from Swift to Kotlin / Jetpack Compose. However, there is a big consideration – this framework is not free for commercial usage, keep it in mind. But if you are in Swift, I think it's fun to give it a try.
You can read docs introduction here

I found a new continent by your guideline. thank you very much


is there any way to build cross-platform apps using Swift?

If you don't meant to construct a brand new mobile app framework, No.
(modified 2024-07-22)
As Sameri11 answered, there's a framework named Skip, which achieves multiplatformness by transpile Swift code into Kotlin and Jetpack.
It will lose performance advantage of native code tho.

Is it possible to build Android Apps with Swift?

Kind of.
You can use native code built from Swift with Android NDK(Native Development Kit).
This is a official guide of Swift about Android NDK, but as the guide says,

You'd need some sort of framework to build a user interface for your application, which the Swift stdlib does not provide.

And NDK is "practically" unusable without a base app made with Java or Kotlin.
For impractical example, you can check an Android app purely made with C in this github repo.
